# What is a (sub)network in the context of TCP/IP stack?

Tags: networking, internet, ip, tcpip

In the context of TCP/IP stack (that is the Internet), is a (sub)network defined as IP address + mask?

If not, then how is a (sub)network defined?

---

Clarificaltion:

Given a complex interconnection of machines like Internet, how would you know identify separate (sub)networks. That is, to say: "these 5 machines are in one (sub)network, these 10 are in other, these 8 are in yet another..."

One machine (both the end-system and the router) can be in multiple (sub)networks at the same time. Do we then consider that this machine is in one network on one interface, and in the second network on the second interface?

Answer (score 1):

That's not usually a technical, but an organizational distinction.

A "network" is a group of connected machines that can operate somewhat autonomously, because it has its own organizational processes so that it remains useful even if the link to the outside world is severed.

Typically, there would be a process for address assignment (such as DHCP, or [RFC2322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2322.txt)), possibly name resolution for local names (DNS, mDNS, WINS/NBNS) and some services inside the network that are the actual reason for connecting the machines in the first place (such as a shared file server, or a server providing login credentials verification.

With the Internet, it is also possible to access resources on a different network than the one you are immediately connected to, which made access-only networks that do not provide any other services a thing (but these still have address assignment and name resolution).

All of these definitions predate vacuum cleaners and doorbells that cease to function when there is an outage in a datacenter on the other side of the world, so the definition of autonomous operation is a bit fuzzy these days -- in principle, these services see the entire Internet as one big network instead of as a collection of smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

No , TCP/IP is not limited to IP addresses, it is a protocol governing the reliable transmission of data across the internet.

Protocols have rules as a standard , things like max bit length, maximum data payload ,handshaking protocols ,reserved addresses,classes ,etc...

Comment: Thanks. You think in the IP protocol the "network" concept is not defined?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a network is a collection of devices connected to one another
to allow the sharing of data.

The important part here is the word "connected", meaning if TCP/IP can be used
for device A to share data with device B, then A and B are on the same network.

TCP/IP or
[Internet protocol suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)
includes many protocols for connecting devices.

I quote:

> A minimal implementation of TCP/IP includes the following:
> Internet Protocol (IP), Address Resolution Protocol (ARP),
> Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP), Transmission Control Protocol (TCP),
> User Datagram Protocol (UDP), and Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP).
> In addition to IP, ICMP, TCP, UDP, Internet Protocol version 6 requires
> Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP), ICMPv6, and IGMPv6 and is often accompanied
> by an integrated IPSec security layer.

The only criteria that is left is that of being reachable by one of the above
protocols.

Comment: Thanks. In the context of this image https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/VPN_overview-en.svg you can see that on the Internet there are multiple networks (subnetworks). Are all subnetworks private networks?

Comment: All local networks behind NAT are private, unless the computers are reachable via port forwarding on the router. Strictly speaking, the whole local network is known on the internet by the one IP address allocated to the router by the ISP, so in that sense it is public but not reachable.

Comment: OK, but if there is a port forwarding, the computers in the private network can communicate with the rest of the internet, but they are in their own network.

Comment: Yes, but internet servers cannot distinguish between the local computers, since they all have externally the same IP.

Comment: OK, but in this context I would like to know the definition of the IP network.

Comment: It is "reachable". If you take out the router, the local network is disconnected from the world and then "network" only means local.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117234/discussion-between-croraf-and-harrymc).

Answer (score 0):

1.According to your description, **"network" in the TCP/IP stack means "The Network Interface Layer"**
It helps you to defines details of how data should be sent using the network.

A network layer is a combination of the data line and defined in the article of OSI reference model. This layer defines how the data should be sent physically through the network. This layer is responsible for the transmission of the data between two devices on the same network.

2."IP" refers to: An Internet Protocol address that is also known as an IP address is a numerical label. It is assigned to each device that is connected to a computer network which uses the IP for communication. Its routing function allows internetworking and essentially establishes the Internet. Combination of IP with a TCP allows developing a virtual connection between a destination and a source.

For more details,https://www.guru99.com/tcp-ip-model.html

Comment: Thanks Gloria. I didn't mean the "network layer", but "one distinct network in this network layer". Given the whole Internet, how would you know to say "these computers are in one (sub)network", "these are in second subnetwork", etc. (I will try to edit the main question as I think it is not clear enough)